# Slider bar with two slider knobs in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a slider with two slider options, one for a minimum price bar and one for a maximum price bar. I tried looking it up but don't know what the options bobbles things are called, if any one knows of any tutorials etc could they let me know thank you.

Comment: [UISlider](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the UISlide of your own or you can use this one.

http://github.com/cmezak/CMRangeSlider

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/rangeslider

Answer (score 1):

Here's something usefull that I've used long time ago :

https://github.com/cmezak/CMRangeSlider